# What is the future direction of Solana?

Tags: ecosystem

I'm curious what the future direction of solana is going to be? For example, in the next six months to one year, what will you do to make solana more competitive? Is there a clear roadmap? Where can I find this relevant information?

Answer (score 1):

[Breakpoint has a bunch of announcements about future Solana direction](https://www.youtube.com/solanafndn).

Summarising:

- Faster transactions (Layer N and Firedancer)
- Ability to mint billions of NFTs at the same time (needed for some gaming apps) using transaction compression
- Less downtime (there's a second Solana validator in the works with an entirely new codebase, so bugs affecting one won't affect the other)
- Google running some nodes, and adding transaction history to their public data sets.
- Support from old-school payments vendors like Stripe and Google.